# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was getting started with **AWS' Elastic Beanstalk**.

I am following this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) to **deploy a Django/PostgreSQL app**.

I did everything before the 'Configuring a Database' section. The deployment was also successful but I am getting an Internal Server Error.

Here's the traceback from the logs:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=30226): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/polly/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Sep 15 12:06:43.472954 2015] [:error] [pid 30226] [remote 172.31.14.126:53947] mod_wsgi (pid=30226): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/polly/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Sep 15 12:06:43.474702 2015] [:error] [pid 30226] [remote 172.31.14.126:53947] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 15 12:06:43.474727 2015] [:error] [pid 30226] [remote 172.31.14.126:53947]   File "/opt/python/current/app/polly/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Sep 15 12:06:43.474777 2015] [:error] [pid 30226] [remote 172.31.14.126:53947]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Sep 15 12:06:43.474799 2015] [:error] [pid 30226] [remote 172.31.14.126:53947] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It appears that `django.core.wsgi` is not in your path. If you know where it is, import sys then sys.path.append('/path/to/it')

Comment: Try it on the the Python interpreter first `import django.core.wsgi`. If it works there, it will work in your code.

Comment: Reading the instructions you posted there, there is a step to configure your Python env and add the necessary path. Did you do it?

Comment: Yes i did that by implementing both option1 and option2

Comment: Also i pip installed django by ssh-ing to the instance and now i can import the module through the python shell but still i am getting the same error when i load the application

Comment: @JaquelinePassos No i moved to a normal ec2 instance

Answer (score 3):

Have you created a `requirements.txt` in the root of your application?  [Elastic Beanstalk will automatically install the packages from this file upon deployment.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/python-configuration-requirements.html)  (Note it might need to be checked into source control to be deployed.)

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

(You will probably want to do that from within a virtualenv so that you only pick up the packages your app actually needs to run.  Doing that with your system Python will pick up every package you've ever installed system-wide.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209268/6169225) by [carl-g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39396/carl-g) is correct. One thing that got me was that `requirements.txt` was in the wrong directory. Let's say you created a django project called `mysite`. This is the directory in which you run the `eb` command(s) --> make sure `requirements.txt` is in this directory.

Comment: Please refer to an answer by the name of the answerer, or with a link to the answer - your answer may be top one day, and "the answer above" won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget the **.ebextensions** folder you will get the same error.

I was following along with a good simple (non Elastic Beanstalk) [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-your-first-python-and-django-application) and missed step 3 & 4 of [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html).

I was using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7