# Django app not launching on Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my Django project on elastic beanstalk I get a 500 Internal Server error. I have tried everything,The EB dashboard looks okay health is perfect and no mention of any errors in there. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
============= i-03980c0f6a1094e3c ==============
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Wed Apr 04 13:15:51.669498 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 3065] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Apr 04 13:15:51.684578 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 3065] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the 
currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Wed Apr 04 13:15:51.684588 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 3065] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Wed Apr 04 13:15:51.685042 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3065] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Apr 04 13:15:51.686951 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3065] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 04 13:15:51.686971 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3065] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:13.037691 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3065] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.092208 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 3287] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.107856 2018] [so:warn] [pid 3287] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.110001 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 3287] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the 
currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.110011 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 3287] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.110578 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3287] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.113943 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3287] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.113964 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3287] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.142312 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)', stopping.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:14.142341 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.869762 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)', stopping.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.869800 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.870482 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.870510 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.870676 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.870699 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:252]   File "/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.870702 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:252]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:16.870716 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:17.873718 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:248] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:17.873768 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:248] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:17.873855 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:248] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:17.873881 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:248]   File "/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:17.873885 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:248]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:17.873899 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:248] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:18.876808 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:2556] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:18.876857 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:2556] mod_wsgi (pid=3292): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/testapi/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 04 13:16:18.876927 2018] [:error] [pid 3292] [remote 127.0.0.1:2556] Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586612/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-in-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: I think its a different error.The answers for that question do not work for me.

Comment: I think you'll need to include more information in your question about how you deployed the project (including your `requirements.txt` file and location as explained in that question. I don't think there's enough detail in your question to show the problem.

Comment: The issue is stated in log you posted `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` which means that django isn't installed in the venv if thats the case you''ll need to install the requirements.txt checkout this guide on deployment https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: Django is installed in my virtualenv it works perfectly on local host. I'll attach my requirements

Comment: ` certifi==2018.1.18
    chardet==3.0.4
    defusedxml==0.5.0
    Django==2.0.4
    django-allauth==0.35.0
    django-rest-auth==0.9.3
    djangorestframework==3.7.7
    djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
    idna==2.6
    numpy==1.14.2
    oauthlib==2.0.7
    pandas==0.22.0
    PyJWT==1.6.1
    python-dateutil==2.7.2
    python3-openid==3.1.0
    pytz==2018.3
    requests==2.18.4
    requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
    scikit-learn==0.19.1
    scipy==1.0.1
    six==1.11.0
    sklearn==0.0
    urllib3==1.22 `

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YAjpL Here is my root directory of my project, I used this guide to deploy via the EB CLI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, you should have a `.elasticbeanstalk` folder, you must have another one `.ebextensions`. If you don't have it, add it.

Then you must create the files to run `some stuff` on the instances that EBT will fire for you. For example, add a file like `10_packages.config` the number is important because will keep the order. The file content is something like that:

```
# 10_packages.config
# Add the packages needed to run the application and some other tools
packages:
    yum:
        git: []
        postgresql94-devel: []
        gcc: []
        gcc-c++: []
        make: []
        libffi-devel: []
        libmemcached-devel: []
        vim-enhanced: []
```

Then you need to install django and all the packages you need for your app. Create a file called `20_pip_requirements.config`

```
# 20_pip_requirements.config
# Update pip in the venv
commands:
  01_upgrade_pip_for_venv:
    command: "sudo /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip"
```

Eventually, you must migrate the database, this must be run just one time. Let's fire another file `30_migrate.config`

```
# 30_migrate.config
container_commands:
  01_migrate_database:
        command: "./manage.py migrate"
        leader_only: true
```

This is just an example, but give you an idea about what you have to do.

Read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) for more info.

Comment: Excellent description. The .elasticbeanstalk folder was what I was missing. I had the django.config file but that was it. Will EB not install the requirements.txt modules automatically?

Comment: Yes, it does. Have a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/python-configuration-requirements.html

Comment: I also added a config to change some configuration with Apache. I had an issue with the http not redirected to https and I solved that with the config. If you need that I can update the answer.

Comment: It still wont work for me. This is my folders now https://imgur.com/a/VJWi8 Same error

Comment: I notice just now that in your log the error are refered to python3.6. This is not possible if you use EBT and the distro provided by Amazon. Last version: "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.6.5 running Python 3.4". If you are trying to change the python version, you are doing wrong because the requirements are installed by EBT in python3.4

Comment: On the new .ebextensions you created, add a numeric prefix to all the files, I see `django.config`, change it to `XX_django.config` where the XX is a number.

Comment: maybe is available in your zone :-(